# quickest way to find an 2d object from co-ordnance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table with 2d objects x and z (there is a y, but for this it doesn't matter), I am trying to find the easiest way to look them up, when I provide a set of co-ordnance.

```
SELECT * FROM RegionName 
WHERE (( "50" between RegionName.X1 and RegionName.X2 )  
AND ( "-66" between RegionName.Z1 and RegionName.Z2 ))    
OR (( "50" between RegionName.X2 and RegionName.X1 )     
AND ( "-66" between RegionName.Z1 and RegionName.Z2 ))    
OR (( "50" between RegionName.X2 and RegionName.X1 )     
AND ( "-66" between RegionName.Z2 and RegionName.Z1 ))    
OR (( "50" between RegionName.X1 and RegionName.X2 )     
AND ( "-66" between RegionName.Z2 and RegionName.Z1 ))
```

Now I have something that works, but I know there should be a nicer way to do this.  I have tried not having every combination of the x and z but it doesn't always work, and this is what I have ended up with.  anyone know how I could reduce this down to 2 or 3 lines.  I tried (below) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT * FROM RegionName 
WHERE ( "50" (between RegionName.X1 and RegionName.X2, between RegionName.X2 and RegionName.X1 ))
AND ( "-66" (between RegionName.Z1 and RegionName.Z2, between RegionName.Z2 and RegionName.Z1))
```

or am I just trying to make more work for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a spatial index, also known as an R-Tree. You can ask, with SQL, if point (50,-66) is within any of the regions. See this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html for how to work with spatial indices and what functions are available for querying them.

Comment: ok, thanks.  This does seem like a whole new thing to learn, and might just be more then I need.